# Javascript changing value in multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I try to to fill a multidimensional Array with the content from an Json file.

The problem is, I can´t update the content in the Array:

```
if(j>i && hoursYy == hoursY && secondsX == secondsXx){
  wocheArray[i].count = wocheArray[i].count + 1;
}
```

My goal was, that "count" counts up, every time I find a duplicate in my JSON file. I couldn't´t find an answer online jet.

just in case, here is the whole code:

```
var myweek;
var x;
var y;
var id;
var count;
var wocheArray = [];

function preload(){
myweek = loadJSON("data/data.json");
}

function setup(){
createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
background(0);

//SAVE IN WOCHEARRAY
for (var i = 0; i < myweek.woche.length; i++) {

hoursY = myweek.woche[i].stunden;
secondsX = myweek.woche[i].sekunden;

for (var j=0; j< myweek.woche.length; j++){
 hoursYy = myweek.woche[j].stunden;
 secondsXx = myweek.woche[j].sekunden;

if(j>i && hoursYy == hoursY && secondsX == secondsXx){
  wocheArray[i].count = wocheArray[i].count + 1;
}

else {
  x = myweek.woche[i].stunden;
  y = myweek.woche[i].sekunden;
  id = myweek.woche[i].person;
  count = 0;
  }
wocheArray[i] = {x, y, count, id};
}
}
console.log(wocheArray);
}
```

Comment: This question will be *easier* to answer with some sample of what is in `data.json`, and _possible_ to answer with the code of your `map` function.

Comment: Probably wocheArray[i][count]

Comment: the data.json looks like that:  `{
  "woche": [
 {
   "stunden": 0,
   "sekunden": 6,
   "person": "b"
 },...`

Comment: I guess it´s easy, since I´m relative new to javascript. I deleted the `map`-elements. But I checked it with `console.log`. The Array wocheArray[ ] is perfect, except the `count` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem reside here :

```
wocheArray[i] = {x, y, count, id};
```

If you check your code you would find that this part is overriding.

Consider your case: If a duplicate is found.

Then what your for loop will do:-

1.) Set `var count = 0;`

2.) [Skipping to If condition where is the procedure to check]

```
//IF match found (at j = 2 location, and i = 1)
//then what happen is : 

if(2>1 && hoursYy == hoursY && secondsX == secondsXx){
   wocheArray[1].count = wocheArray[1].count + 1;
// from here the count of wocheArray[1] would be increased by 1, Suppose 1.
}
```

3) In else block it will again set `count = 0;`

4) Again you are trying to set the values of `wocheArray[1] = {x, y, count, id};` //now wocheArray[1] count is set to 0.

So from here, you can see you are updating the values or overriding them which creating the undesired result.

You should not call this outside `wocheArray[i] = {x, y, count, id};`

You must call it inside else block to make it work correctly.

```
else{
x = ....
....
....
count = 0;
wocheArray[i] = {x, y, count, id};
}
```

However, I am curious about the using of `count = 0;` inside else block as it does nothing here and `var count =0;` inside the for block which just re-initializes count variable which is wasting memory or not a good practice. According to shown code sample.

Answer (score 0):

If you format your code a bit better, you will see that

```
wocheArray[i] = {x, y, count, id};
```

is outside your `if else`. So wocheArray[i] is overwritten at the end of every loop.